# how to align divs when multiple divs are disturbing its alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have been trying to line up several divs in a row. I have 8 divs next to each other, but when I try to allign the 2nd row, I can only fit one div in. I need help

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body bgcolor="H70D4R334">
    <title>Ordinate</title>
    <head>
        <style text/css> 

    #div1{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-right:500px;
        margin-left:400px;
        border:0px solid blue;
    }
    #div2{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-right:50px;
        border:0px solid blue;
    }
    #div3{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:300px;
        margin-right:5px;
        border:0px solid green;
    }
    #div4{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:300px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:0px solid green;
    }
    #div5{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:300px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:0px solid green;
    }
    #div6{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:300px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:0px solid green;
    }
    #div7{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:300px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:0px solid green;
    }
    #div8{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:300px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:0px solid green;
    }
    #div10{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:400px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    #div11{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    #div12{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    #div13{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:1px solid green;        
    }
    #div14{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    #div15{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    #div16{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    #div17{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    #Button{
        float:center;
        width:200px;
        height:50px;
        margin:25px;
    }

    </style>



    <script>
    var dragSrcEl = null;
    var draggSrcID = null;

        function dragStart(ev) {
        draggSrcID = ev.target.id;
        dragSrcEl = ev.target;
        ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.outerHTML);
        }

        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(draggSrcID));
            ev.preventDefault();
        } 

        function swapDrop(ev) {

          if (ev.stopPropagation) {
            ev.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
          }

          // Don't do anything if dropping the same image we're dragging.
          if (dragSrcEl != ev.target) {
            // Set the source image to the HTML of the image we're dropping on.
            srcEl = document.getElementById(draggSrcID);
            srcEl.outerHTML = ev.target.outerHTML;
            ev.target.outerHTML = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
           }
            ev.preventDefault();
        }       

    </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><font size="10">Ordinate</font></center>
        <div id="div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        </div>
        <div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        </div>
        <div id="div12" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        </div>
        <div id="div13" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        </div>
        <div id="div14" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        </div>
        <div id="div15" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        </div>
        <div id="div16" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        </div>
        <div id="div17" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        </div> 
        <div id="div1" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img id="D" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=D&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" />
        </div>
        <div id="div2" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img id="E" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=E&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
        </div>
        <div id="div3" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img id="I" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=I&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">  
        </div>
        <div id="div4" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        <img id="T" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=T&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
        </div>
        <div id="div5" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        <img id="A" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=A&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
        </div>
        <div id="div6" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        <img id="N" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=N&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">  
        </div>
        <div id="div7" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        <img id="O" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=O&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
        </div>
        <div id="div8" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
        <img id="R" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=R&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">  
        </div>
        <center><input id="Button" type="submit" value="Click me to check" onclick="HitEnter()"></center>
        <script>
            word = "ordinate"
            function HitEnter() {
                for (i = 10, str = ""; i <= 17; i++) {
                    if (document.getElementById("div" + i).childNodes.length > 1) {
                        str += document.getElementById("div" + i).childNodes[1].id
                    }
                }
                if (str.toLowerCase() == word) {
                    alert("Good job!!!")
                }
                else {
                alert('You got the word incorrect! Please try again.')

                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am a beginner at css, js, and html. I will appreciate any help I can get. Thank You!

Comment: What does this mean? `<style text/.css> `?

Comment: sorry, i didn't edit that.

Comment: You do not need to style each and evry div individually. Just add the style once for div or add a class

Comment: @FrankProvost, when I try that, the divs get spaced apart, more than i want them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set following attributes for you div with the id 1

```
margin-right: 500px;
margin-left: 400px;
```

therefore it's positioned 400 px away from left border. Since you also have margin right set, the next element to it's right is set 500px away. This is why your rows break.

Edit:

how to fix it: Remove all

```
margin-right
```

from your second row and add

```
margin-left: 5px
```

to have it the same as the other row

Comment: How do i align div 1 directly under div 10 without doing that?

Comment: When I try to do that, It doesn't align properly. It would be a big help if you could directly edit the code.

Comment: If you want me to directly edit your code you should provide a jsfiddle of your wor

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2bao8er7/1/ here is your code re-organized and somehow fixed. I think someone mentioned it before that there are better ways to style your code than refering to every div